# Simplest "Back" transition ui-router-ng2

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I've seen that in html a uiSref="^" can be used to perform a "window history back", but how can this be achieved in code?  At the moment I have a state : StateService and trans : Transition and use the following code...

```
state.go(trans.from());
```

Which seems a bit convoluted.  Is there a simpler/tidier way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`uiSref="^"` actually means "go to parent state".  You can do this in code too: `state.go("^")`

There is no built-in mechanism to do a history back in ui-router. You can use the built in browser APIs instead.

Did you mean to go to the previous state, I think your example code is simple enough: `state.go(trans.from());` --  literally: go to the state that I came from.